# Skipping tuples without attributes Python NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I have a script that is mostly working for the Natural Language Tool Kit. It works by using NLTK to tokenize and label (categorize) individual words.

When my list includes names and entities it works fine.

Where it breaks down is if the list includes articles of speech such as "The", "a", "and" etc.

These are words that are not going to receive labels from NLTK (Persons, Organization, Geographic Location etc..)

My question is there is a way to skip the tuples that will give me an error because they will not return a label attribute?

Example dataframe:

```
Order   Text    results
0   0   John    
1   1   Paul    
2   2   George  
3   3   Ringo
```

### (Obviously not perfect, but better than nothing)

Code:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    SENT_DETECTOR = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    ne_tree = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text[i])))
    df['results'][i] = ne_tree[0].label()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Order    Text results
0      0    John  PERSON
1      1    Paul  PERSON
2      2  George     GPE
3      3   Ringo     GPE
```

Example dataframe 2:

```
   Order    Text
0      0    John
1      1    Paul
2      2  George
3      3      to
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dff2775636f0> in <module>
      2     SENT_DETECTOR = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
      3     ne_tree = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text[i])))
----> 4     df['results'][i] = ne_tree[0].label()
      5 print(df)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'label'
```

The "to" is causing it to crash because "to" would not get a label. If I'm dealing with thousands of words it would not be practical to find all the words that would cause it to crash and remove them manually. Ideally I would like to skip problematic lines, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about error handling with `try/catch` and `continue`?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to remove stop words (to, the, a, etc). Example code is:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, wordnet    
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
df['TextRemovedStopWords'] = df['Text']
df.loc[df['Text'].isin(stop_words),'TextRemovedStopWords'] = None
```

After that you can use try and except to handle the edge cases

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
import nltk
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
def get_result(text):
    if text is not None:
        try:
            ne_tree = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
            return ne_tree[0]
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e, text)
            return None
    else:
        return None
df['results'] = df['TextRemovedStopWords'].apply(lambda x:get_result(x))
```

You can also skip the removing stop words part, but in general it is better to always remove stop words. Hope it helps.